# How can I map a physical address to a userspace virtual address suitable for get_user_pages_fast()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, embedded-linux

I'm aware there are a few ways to determine the mapping of a virtual address to a physical one, but I need a virtual address which maps to a *specific* physical one. I'm working with a DMA driver in an embedded system, running a fork of kernel 4.14, and need to pass a userspace virtual address to a kernel module which sets up a scatter-gather list.

I have a working example where the userspace code allocates a page of memory, then initializes it:

```
txbuffer = (unsigned char *) memalign(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE),buffer_len);
memset((unsigned char *)txbuffer, 'Z', buffer_len);
```

Then passes it to the kernel module with:

```
ret = pwrite(datafd, txbuffer, buffer_len, offset);
```

And the kernel module pins this userspace memory into kernel memory:

```
err = get_user_pages_fast((unsigned long) txbuffer, num_alloc_pages,
              !(direction), cache_pages);
```

**My issue** is, this `txbuffer` is some arbitrary buffer with arbitrary data. I need to instead pass a `txbuffer` which points to memory located at a given physical address. I tried to get a userspace virtual address by `mmap`-ing /dev/mem, which works for other cases where I need to access a physical address from userspace:

```
unsigned char *mem;
memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
mem = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED, memfd, phys_addr);
```

But when I pass the virtual address `mem` to the kernel module, `get_user_pages_fast` returns `-EFAULT`.

How can I correctly allocate this buffer, assigning a userspace virtual address which maps to `phys_addr`, which can be pinned by `get_user_pages_fast`? Or, is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: *"Or, is there a more correct way to do this?"* -- IMO the _only_ correct way is have the kernel own this memory region and perform the mapping, not userspace.

Comment: Can you map the desired physical address to a virtual address in the system space so that it never moves?

Comment: I could, but I was hoping to avoid rewriting the driver module in several places. I was hoping there was a way to do it while keeping most of the driver intact.